# Post receive not working

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I trying to push changes to my server with post receive.
In the main path: /home/user
I executed those commands:

```
mkdir repos
cd repos
mkdir test.git
cd test.git
git init --bare
cd hooks
nano post-receive
```

and I put those lines in post-receive file:

```
#!/bin/sh
git —work-tree=/home/user/public_html/testfolder —git-dir=/home/user/repos/test.git checkout -f
chmod +x post-receive
```

It was created successfully.
Then I add a new remote to my local repo:

```
git remote add prod ssh://user@domain.com:22/home/user/repos/test.git
```

then I pushed:
git push -u prod master

I got success message:

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 430 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://domain.com:22/home/user/repos/test.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from prod.
```

But there in no files in the testfolder (my work-tree) - why?

Please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: `chmod +x post-receive` does not go *into* a post-receive as a command to be run *later* once the post-receive script gets run. It must be run *right away*, so that the post-receive script becomes executable. Until the post-receive script is executable, it will not be run. With that line in it, running it could make it executable, but first it must be run, which it can't be yet!

Comment: Hooks are repo-specific.  Receive runs on the receiving end. Put the hook in the prod server's repo to run it there.

Comment: which operating system are you working @ronjacob

Answer (score 1):

> there in no files in the testfolder (my work-tree)

Make sure your [server-side `post-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) is in

```
user@domain.com:22/home/user/repos/test.git/hooks/post-receive
```

(and is executable)